# React.js - setState after calculation based on props

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a component that receives images as props, performs some calculation on them, and as a result I need to update its class. But if I use `setState` after the calculation, I get the warning that I shouldn't update state yet... How should I restructure this?

```
class MyImageGallery extends React.Component { 

    //[Other React Code]

    getImages() {
       //Some calculation based on this.props.images, which is coming from the parent component
       //NEED TO UPDATE STATE HERE?
    }

    //componentWillUpdate()? componentDidUpdate()? componentWillMount()? componentDidMount()? {

      //I CAN ADD CLASS HERE USING REF, BUT THEN THE COMPONENT'S
      // FIRST RENDERED WITHOUT THE CLASS AND IT'S ONLY ADDED LATER
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div ref="galleryWrapper" className={GET FROM STATE????} 
                <ImageGallery
                    items={this.getImages()}
                />
            </div>
        );
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your logic into componentWillReceiveProps (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) so as to do a prop transition before render occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In the end what we did was run the logic in the constructor and then put the class into the initial state:

```
class MyImageGallery extends React.Component { 

 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.getImages = this.getImages.bind(this);
        this.images = this.getImages();
        this.state = {smallImgsWidthClass: this.smallImgsWidthClass};
    }

getImages() {
   //Some calculation based on this.props.images, which is coming from the parent component
    this.smallImgsWidthClass = '[calculation result]';
    return this.props.images;
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className={this.state.smallImgsWidthClass } 
            <ImageGallery
                items={this.images}
            />
        </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: This is not good practice as should this.props.images update the smallImgsWidthClass would not as it is set in the constructor. You should use componentWillReceiveProps  as mentioned above.